# Is there any way to speed up Python turtle past speed(0)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm writing code in Python using turtle to visualise a bubble sort but it's very slow. Is there any way I can speed it up because `speed(0)` for Python turtle is not quick enough. Or are there any other ways of doing this sort of project using Python?

Comment: I think `11` is the fastest (“It goes up to 11”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is confirm that it's the turtle graphics that's slowing things down.  For example, run your bubble sort with and without the graphics to see how much time is really lost.

One way to speed up turtle graphics, which you should approach carefully, is using `tracer()`:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
# ...
screen.tracer(False)  # turn off graphic updates
# ...
# Whenever you make a change you want the user to see:
screen.update()  # make screen current
# ...
# When you're completely finished:
screen.tracer(True)  # turn graphics updates back on
# ...
screen.mainloop()
```

You don't need `speed(0)` (aka `speed('fastest')`) in this scenario though it won't hurt to leave it.  Some graphic operations will force `screen.update()` independent of your calls to it -- don't be surprised.  Make sure to `tracer(True)` at the end so things like hiding the turtle work properly.

Finally, add a minimal, working example of your code to your question above for a proper review.